# How do I know whether a UITableViewCell currently exists?

Tags: ios

Given the `indexPath` of a UITableViewCell, I want to know whether the cell currently exists.

I know how to check if it's on the screen (use `tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows`). However, I also want to know if it's off the screen but already created (assuming the user has scrolled but it hasn't quite entered the screen are yet).

How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you think you need to know this? What will you do with this information?

Comment: @rdelmar I am fetching from a database in the background, and sometimes when it is done fetching, the cell no longer exists and has been reused. I don't want to set the wrong cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reusing cells by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, the tableView will perform like a conveyer. The cell who has been scrolled off screen will immediately transfer to the cell who is going to enter the screen. Theoretically, the tableView won't create cells more than a screen for you. So it's meaningless that you want to know about the cell off the screen.

`UITableViewCell` is just a view according to [MVC Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). It is your model, your data, that decide what should be present in a specific cell at a specific indexPath. Your code would probably go like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // dequeue a cell
    // ...
    if (!cell)
    {
        // init a cell
        // ...
    }

    // for a given indexPath, decide what should be presented in the cell, something like updating the cell's properties
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.data dataShouldBePresentedAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do

```
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

(not to be confused with the data source method `[self tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`) and if a cell for that index path exists, it will be returned. Otherwise, you'll get `nil`.

You definitely don't want your background update process to hold a direct reference the cell because, as you said, it may have scrolled off screen and been recycled by the time the fetch completes. Instead, hold a reference to the index path or some piece of data that can be used to look up the index path and then use that index path with the above method to retrieve the cell.

Answer (score 2):

The only cells that exist are the ones that are currently visible.  As soon as the cell scrolls outside of the view, the cell object is made available to the [UITableViewCell `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3a), which is how the OS conserves memory when dealing with massive amounts of table data to be displayed in such a small amount of real estate.

If you want to keep track of which cells have already been seen, you should modify the underlying objects to have some kind of BOOL or value set when the the object data is fed to a table view cell in your app's "`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`" method.

Comment: What about cells that are about to enter the screen in response to the user scrolling? Are they created right before they're visible on the screen?

Comment: If they don't exist in memory, they're created via the "`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`" method (which happens in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method).

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 3**

```
let YOURINDEXPATH = IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0)

if tableView.cellForRow(at: YOURINDEXPATH) != nil {

    // DO YOUR STUFFS HERE
}
```

> define your index path (YOURINDEXPATH ) accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // dequeue a cell
    // ...
    if (cell == nill)
    {
        // init a cell
        // ...
    }

    // for a given indexPath, decide what should be presented in the cell, something like updating the cell's properties
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.data dataShouldBePresentedAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

you can check cell is exist or not.... hope this works... :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do something like this

```
-(BOOL) isRowPresentInTableView:(int)row withSection:(int)section
{
    if(section < [self.tableView numberOfSections])
    {
        if(row < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section])
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```